# how to do a git diff of current commit with last commit using gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to grasp gitpython module,

```
hcommit = repo.head.commit
tdiff = hcommit.diff('HEAD~1')
```

but `tdiff = hcommit.diff('HEAD^ HEAD')` doesn't work !! neither does `('HEAD~ HEAD')`.,

I am trying to get the diff output !

Comment: I admit to never having used the gitpython code, but it seems obvious that if hcommit is `repo.head.commit`, it's bound to that *particular* commit, and thus `hcommit.diff` means "diff that particular commit, against something else".  To get diffs of two arbitrary commits, you'd have to choose some other starting-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get the git diff using gitPython.

```
import git
repo = git.Repo("path/of/repo/")

# the below gives us all commits
repo.commits()

# take the first and last commit

a_commit = repo.commits()[0]
b_commit = repo.commits()[1]

# now get the diff
repo.diff(a_commit,b_commit)
```

Voila !!!

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Repo' object has no attribute 'diff'`, and `Repo.diff` is not mentioned in the [API doc](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html). Does this answer need to be updated?

Comment: I haven't found `commits()` method for `repo`
I have done :
import git
repo_url = "<REPO URL>"
repo = git.Repo(repo_url)
commit_list = list(repo.iter_commits())[0]

Answer (score 8):

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('repo_path')
commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())

# --- To compare the current HEAD against the bare init commit
a_commit = commits_list[0]
b_commit = commits_list[-1]

a_commit.diff(b_commit)
```

This will return a diff object for the commits. There are other ways to achieve this as well. For example (this is copy/pasted from http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#obtaining-diff-information):

```

```
    hcommit = repo.head.commit
    hcommit.diff()                  # diff tree against index
    hcommit.diff('HEAD~1')          # diff tree against previous tree
    hcommit.diff(None)              # diff tree against working tree

    index = repo.index
    index.diff()                    # diff index against itself yielding empty diff
    index.diff(None)                # diff index against working copy
    index.diff('HEAD')              # diff index against current HEAD tree
```

```

Answer (score 2):

To get the contents of the diff:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo("path/of/repo/")

# define a new git object of the desired repo
gitt = repo.git
diff_st = gitt.diff("commitID_A", "commitID_B")
```

Answer (score 1):

For a proper solution (without using git command callback), you have to use create_patch option.

To compare current index with previous commit:

```
diff_as_patch = repo.index.diff(repo.commit('HEAD~1'), create_patch=True)
print(diff_as_patch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to dig up an old thread... If you need to find out which files changed, you can use the `.a_path` or `.b_path`  attribute of a diff object depending on which one you feed it first.  In the example below I'm using the head commit as `a` so I look at `a`.

e.g:

```
# this will compare the most recent commit to the one prior to find out what changed.

from git import repo

repo = git.Repo("path/to/.git directory")
repoDiffs = repo.head.commit.diff('HEAD~1')

for item in repoDiffs:
    print(item.a_path)
```